# how bitcoin reject invalid transaction? (with createrawtransaction)

Tags: bitcoind

i'm studying 'Mastering Bitcoin' and have a questions,

in this book, we can send coin to other wallet by `createrawtransaction` but there is no enough secure method.

we can find other's wallet addresses at https://www.blockchain.com. and unused coin value too.

for example - https://www.blockchain.com/en/btc/address/34bN2MQcqA4JpbEVRU9KBsvhXgSEHQrqBz

> 718ae88f0eb13d2f2d3bc74cbf18721a82739b80f1bfc0658ed699263fca76fd(Fee:
>   0.00002057 BTC - 3.11 sat/WU - 8.33 sat/B - Size: 247 bytes) 2019-01-14 04:57:04 34bN2MQcqA4JpbEVRU9KBsvhXgSEHQrqBz (1.13215222 BTC
>   - Output) 32T5urH6uN4jhKenhW4LWM66WouzSCERbA - (Spent) 0.03213165 BTC **3LnZGyRAeCA3LAMBU2RSQn6dAkHw8rWquw** - (Unspent) 1.1 BTC

than we can make fake transaction such as

> $bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction '[{"txid" :
>   "718ae88f0eb13d2f2d3bc74cbf18721a82739b80f1bfc0658ed699263fca76fd","vout":0}]'
>   ' {"MY WALLET ADDRESS": 1.0, "**3LnZGyRAeCA3LAMBU2RSQn6dAkHw8rWquw**":
>   fee}'

in conclusion, it doesn't works but i want know why this code not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in conclusion, it doesn't works but i want know why this code not working

This part `{"MY WALLET ADDRESS": 1.0, "3LnZGyRAeCA3LAMBU2RSQn6dAkHw8rWquw": fee}` will throw an error, but the more general answer about security is:

You can only generate a valid transaction if the wallet file you have open contains the private keys that can sign the transaction you've made. **If you can't produce a valid signature, then it will not be a valid transaction, and the network will not relay or confirm it.**

Comment: i think createrawtransaction working [{"txid ", "my wallet address", "another wallet address"}] so where is validation part on this command?

Comment: @user10865941: All other nodes validate the transaction - they check that you have provided proof that you posess the private key.

Comment: @user10865941 the output of `createrawtransaction` is an unsigned bitcoin transaction. Next you would need to call `signrawtransaction` to create a valid transaction, but your client will be unable to do so unless it has the relevant private keys. If you cannot produce a valid signature, then the network will not accept it as a valid transaction.

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot spend bitcoins of a given BTC address if you do not own the private key of such address. Only private keys allows you to sign and broadcast a valid spendable tx.**

It's safe to specify also some peculiarity of `creatrawtransaction` RPC:

The `createrawtransaction` RPC command creates an unsigned transaction that will spend a previous output to a new output with a P2PKH or P2SH address. 
*The transaction is not stored in the wallet or transmitted to the network at this stage. It needs to be signed with a valid corresponding private key for the address we want to spend address from.*

Given Parameter #1 (references to previous outputs) & Parameter #2 (P2PKH or P2SH addresses and amounts) we get a result in the forum of an unsigned raw transaction in hex.

Comment: i guess! rawtransaction needs signing. so without signrawtransaction, block will reject this transaction